# PowerMock Mockito ignore junit FixMethodOrder

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4, powermock

I have a little problem here, and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a class which have to make tests for some JSF beans.
In order to achieve that, I used PowerMock with Mockito for mocking the FacesContext, RequestContext and another static methods which are used inside the JSF beans.

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStaticMethods.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTestingClass extends SomeTestBaseClass{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws Exception{
        //mocking the FacesContext and others
    }

    @Test
    public void test0001Create(){}

    @Test
    public void test0002Edit(){}

    @Test
    public void test0003Delete(){}
}
```

The SomeTestBaseClass, nothing complicated.

```
public abstract class SomeTestBaseClass {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        //...
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the order of tests is ignored (even with the FixMethodOrder annotation). If I remove PowerMockRunner (and the RunWith annotation), the order is kept but the mocking for static (and void) methods doesn't work. 
But leaving the class with PowerMockRunner, the annotation @FixMethodOrder is ignored, totally.

I even tried with MockitoJUnitRunner, and here the order of tests is kept, but the mocking for static (and void) methods isn't done.

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Put your workaround into answer section

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem getting them to run in the right order.
I solved it by using the `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` annotation.

In my test class annotations:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

I added `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnit4.class)`:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnit4.class)
```

They now run in the expected order.
I believe this works because then it's not PowerMock that's running the tests, but JUnit 4 itself.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was trying to solve this issue for several days. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like a workaround: Create a new method (let's say 'testAll'), put @Test annotation just for this (remove the @Test annotation from the rest of the methods), and then, call your testing methods inside of the annoted method.

Dirty, but it works.

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStaticMethods.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTestingClass extends SomeTestBaseClass{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws Exception{
        //mocking the FacesContext and others
    }

    @Test
    public void testAll(){
        this.test0001Create();
        this.test0002Edit();
        this.test0003Delete();
    }

    public void test0001Create(){}

    public void test0002Edit(){}

    public void test0003Delete(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work with the `PowerMockRunner` annotation but instead you could use a [`PowerMockRule`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule)

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTestingClass extends SomeTestBaseClass {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws Exception {
        // mocking the FacesContext and others
    }
    @Test
    public void test0001Create() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test0002Create() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test0003Create() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
 ... 50 more

Comment: @CiobanuAndrei strange since i have tested it. I guess that you did not provide all the code.

Comment: Seems that this problem is encountered by many people. https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=414
I'm not the only one who have this exception. And also, I don't know which is the cause... Odd:|

Comment: Could you provides an SSCCE ?

Comment: Meanwhile I did a refactor because I didn't want anymore a methods' order, and I can't reproduce the issue anymore :| Anyway, I'm gonna try again in week-end, and I hope that I will be able to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change sequence:

1. `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`
2. `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
3. `@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStaticMethods.class)`